# Handle JWT Token validation failute in Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

Hi I have added the jwt validate tag to one of the operation in my api management service as shown below

```
<!-- validate the bearerToken !-->
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" output-token-variable-name="jwtOutput">
        <openid-config url="{{OPENIDConfigURL}}" />
        <issuers>
            <issuer>{{tokenIssuer}}</issuer>
        </issuers>
    </validate-jwt>
```

while testing the same with invalid JWT token I am getting internal server error but its not getting captured in my  tag. Am i missing something here.

```
<on-error>
    <base />
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="200" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>{
                    {{FailResponse}};                        
                }</set-body>
    </return-response>
</on-error>
```

Any leads on how to capture the error when the provided jwt token is invalid (for any reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're getting an internal server error because your policy on-error is invalid.
Have a look to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies) and adjust your policy on-error. You can basically use the sample they have available in that link. The errors list shows you the list of errors you can expect from the validate-jwt policy.

Comment: Thanks @hugo updated the policy.
<on-error><base /><set-variable name="myResponse" value="" /><choose><!-- If the token validation failed !--><when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 401)"><set-variable name="myResponse" value="{{token-failure-response}}" /></when></choose><return-response><set-status code="200" /><set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override"><value>{{ContentType_Application_Json}}</value></set-header><set-body>@{return (string)context.Variables["myResponse"]; }</set-body></return-response></on-error>

Comment: Well done! I am glad you were able to solve the problem!